# Java Graphics Basics: Creating Collison Area From Image

Tags: java, android, image, game-physics

I'm trying to get the length and width of an image to create a collision detection area for a basic game. I hope in the end to move it onto android, so I'm avoiding use of the BufferedImage class (which android doesn't seem to have). Instead, I want to read a .png from an assets folder within my Eclipse project, and hand it to a sprite class. All sprites will inherit from ASprite(), which contains a HitBox() class:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;


public class HitBox {

    private int TopLeftX;
    private int TopLeftY;
    private int Width;
    private int Length;

    public void createManually(int topx, int topy, int width, int length){
        TopLeftX = topx;
        TopLeftY = topy;
        Width = width;
        Length = length;
    }

    public void createFromImage(Image i, int topx, int topy){
          //TODO...
    }

   //Various getting and setting functions, & testIntersect(HitBox h1)

}
```

For Sprites that I want to have a custom collision area, I can manually pass in the diameters for the HitBox(). For the rest, I want to be able to take in an image and an X and Y position for the top left corner, and extract the height and width of the image into variables to define the hitbox. I think it will involve using ImageObserver, but I'm having some trouble understanding how to do it. I hope someone can help.

Comment: If you want to know how to get the width and height of an Image, passing null for the observer will probably work fine. If you want to know how to read a PNG on Android, it's with the BitmapFactory class, and it creates Bitmaps, not Images. At any rate, hitboxes, collisions and game physics have nothing to do with it and make your question very confusing. Context to a question is good only when it's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to write an interface.Lets call it ImageInterface. Now in image interface you can have all basic image related stuff like `getWitdh()`, `getHeight()`, `getPixelValue(x,y)`,`draw()` etc. Use that interface in all of your project. And implement it seperately for cros platforms. You can use `BufferedImage` for java and `Bitmap` for Android.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm understanding exactly what you want, but if you are say using Bitmap objects to hold your images, you can simply get the image W/H like this:

```
// Load an image from the drawable folder.
Bitmap tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myContext.getResources(), R.drawable.<nameofimageinresources>);
// get w and h of it and put it in vars.
<put it in some vars> = tempBitmap.getWidth();
<put it in some vars> = tempBitmap.getHeight();
```

Or what is it your looking for?

Comment: Basically, my problem is that I want to write and test my applet as a basic java project, and then try to migrate it to android. Android games seem to rely on BitmapFactory, which seems android specific, whilst Java games tend to be written with bufferedImage, which android doesn't have.